# Low memory feature selection in r

Tags: r, memory, feature-selection

I'm making a text classification model on a large corpus, however fitting models takes a long time since I'm working with over 15k features in my model. So I wanted to reduce this by feature selection. Most ordinary feature selections like `findCorrelation()` and `rfeControl`causes memory issues. Do any of you know feature selection methods that dont require a lot of memory?

Notes:
- This is already a small fraction of the complete corpus, so subsetting even more isn't ideal.
- I'm already working on the strongest possible workspace.

Comment: Rather than subsetting the corpus have you considered subsetting your features?

Comment: are you using a sparse feature matrix? presumably the vast majority of your features are highly sparse

Comment: this: https://topepo.github.io/caret/pre-processing.html#zero--and-near-zero-variance-predictors